# Are there PHP browsers?

Tags: php

Do browsers exist that would allow a person on a Mac to view a PHP file without uploading it and without having it enabled(And having no possibility of enabling it)?

I wasn't asking about how to run it without a server. I was asking about whether a file browser exists that allows me to see the output of the file instead of the source code, if installing anything is not an option.

Comment: PHP is a sever-side language.  You need a web server to process the PHP page.  I don't think there are web browsers that can process PHP files.

Comment: You probably mean application instead of browser. Also what do you mean by *enabling it*? Do you want to see the source code, or the result of running the PHP script?

Comment: Some IDEs come with a builtin PHP interpreter and webserver and also a rudimentary browser. But that's the furthest laziness would allow to browse PHP without some setup.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is not possible without installing PHP usually like others have mentioned, **but** you can use a product like [LitePXP](http://litepxp.com/) to run your code without installation from a USB Key, CD ROM or hard drive.

The blurb from their site:

> LitePXP is a completely portable
>   application which includes Apache,
>   MySQL and PHP 5.3. LitePXP will enable
>   you to run your PHP applications
>   directly from a CD/DVD, USB stick or
>   hard disk without any installation.
>   You can use LitePXP to put your PHP
>   website on a CD/DVD to distribute to
>   clients. Your clients need only to
>   insert the CD/DVD. Then LitePXP starts
>   automatically and shows the website's
>   pages from the CD/DVD. Of course, you
>   can also use LitePXP to put your PHP
>   website on a USB flash drive or other
>   p> ortable media for distribution to
>   your clients.

There is also [iNewPHP](http://www.inewphp.com/index.html) which looks remarkably similar to LitePXP. [MicroWeb](http://www.indigostar.com/microweb.php) by IndigoStar is another one I have heard of.

I should point out that I have never used these products myself... Just heard about them.

Answer (score 5):

You may be looking for the [PHP CLI](http://php.net/manual/en/features.commandline.php). With that you can run PHP scripts in a serverless environment.

```
$ php my_script.php
```

Another option, if you want a server (HTTP) environment, would be to install a local server accessible via `http://localhost`. I personally like [XAMPP](http://www.apachefriends.org/en/xampp-macosx.html), but options are plenty.

Answer (score 1):

The webserver doesn't provide the source for php. You will need to use a file-download program to get it directly from the server.

Comment: I think s/he means a browser that'll execute the PHP, without it needing to be on a server.

Comment: That will not be possible to have, as a browser would only be able to process it if it got the source, which a PHP-based server won't send.

Comment: @Orbling `[s]he` or `(s)he` would be a better way to express an option. `s/he` is usually used for alternation. :)

Comment: @Alin Purcaru: Regardless of what is better (I agree with you), the slash form appears to be the standard method in modern writing.

Answer (score 0):

Not to my knowledge, though it is easy to setup a development server for testing on.

Have a look at [MAMP](http://www.mamp.info/en/index.html), a combined package that provides an Apache server, PHP, MySQL all for the Mac.

Then you can use http://localhost/ to view websites locally.

[image: MAMP Control Panel]

Answer (score 0):

No.

Worst case scenario, it should almost always be possible to build PHP and a web server in your home directory, and then run the web server with it listening on a non-privileged port (higher than 1024).

Answer (score 0):

Server side scripts need to be run on a web server for the output to be generated. You can install local servers on Macs for testing.

If you just want to view the PHP code contained in the .php file then any text editor would do it.

Answer (score 0):

If you mean to run a PHP file, get a web server such as MAMP, (I heard it is very easy to install and get running - I use the windows version, WAMP) and copy the php files to the www folder. Then go on any browser (such as Opera or Safari) and navigate to http://localhost/nameoffile.php .
If you want to view a formatted version of the source code, download a code editor.
If you want to view the source code of a php file hosted on a server you don't have access to... you can't because the script is executed on the server side.

Answer (score 0):

```
$ php yourscript.php
```

or

```
$ php -r "echo time();"
```

If you need a AMP solution, i recommend MAMP or Macports packages